# Filemaker determine if in Web Direct mode?

Tags: scripting, filemaker

In Filemaker, is there a function or a way, perhaps a Get function, that can determine whether this is being viewed as a WebDirect or not?  This way I can alternate some incompatible controls such as printing and saving as a PDF.

Comment: http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/func_ref1.32.150.html#1069388 -- Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks sir, exactly what I was looking for, which will lead me to yet a different question I shall now post...

Answer (score 2):

As @michael.hor257k pointed out, [`Get ( SystemPlatform )`](http://filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/func_ref1.32.150.html#1069388) is the function you're interested in using.

I'll add that I usually have a custom function I call something like `IsWebDirect` that returns the following:

```
Get ( SystemPlatform ) = 4
```

Then I'm able to have self-commenting calculations, such as `If [ IsWebDirect ]`. Obviously, I create similar custom functions for `IsDesktop`, `IsMobile`, etc.

I published a standard library of such functions (and many more) on [GitHub](https://github.com/chivalry/filemaker-custom-functions), if you're interested.